# How do I enter a DateTime value in the VS QuickWatch window?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to change some DateTime data in a QuickWatch window. 
I have tried 1/29/2009, etc. but none of them seem to work. It just keeps going back to #12:00:00 AM#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it inside of pound symbols (#) Like...

```
#1/29/2009#
```

Comment: This simply doesn't work.  Changing the value to #1/29/2009# results in a popup from Visual Studio stating "Unexpected character '#'"

Comment: It works for me in the QuickWatch window when editing the value of a DateTime object at run-time on Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 10):

The Year/Month/Hour/etc fields in DateTime are immutable.  You can't change them in QuickWatch.  You can only change it by reassigning.  Just change the value by constructing a new one.  In other words, enter "new DateTime(2009, 29, 1)" in the Value section.