# QuickWatch/Immediate window cannot set new DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, immediate-window

I have a **c#** model with a `DateTime` property `LastActivityDate`, and I am trying to change it date to something else (some back date) while debugging from *Quick Watch* window (also tried immediate window). But when I do so, I got crash

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

**Error Description**
[image]

It works if I do following:

```
processingDates.LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now
```

But doesn't work with following:

```
processingDates.LastActivityDate = new DateTime(2016,6,12)
```

Could not get the reason for this even after scratching my head for some hours.

Does anyone has a clue?

> Note: The class is `public`, and the property is **not readonly** (also `public`). Just a simple `get;set;` property

**Edit** (adding code to remove confusion that `processingDates` might be `null`):

(*I don't want to change code, so while debugging I am changing value just after instantiating*)

```
var processingDates = new MyClassParameter()
{
    StopRecurrenceProcessDate = DateTime.Now,
    NextProcessingDate = DateTime.Now,
    LastActivityDate = DateTime.Now
};

if (projectId <= 0) //I AM Changing value in quick watch here
```

Comment: it sounds like `processingDates` is null; without context, I can't see how we can really comment much here...

Comment: Thats the first impression of error @MarcGravell. But as mentioned in the question, the other code works on same model, and in same Watch/Immediate window

Comment: You have some other problem here than since you get the error because `processingDates` is null. You would have first to instantiate `processingDates` in immediate window and than modify the `LastActivityDate`

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic if processing date was null, the other code mentioned in the question will also not work in same Watch window. Also it is not null as I see while debugging

Comment: Edited question, added some code. @Nikola.Lukovic.

Comment: Am I only in the world to get this problem? :)

Comment: I believe this is the solution you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182977/how-to-edit-a-datetime-variable-during-visual-studio-2013-debug-session/46183277